# Node.js compute server

Tags: node.js, computation

I want to build a compute server with node.js

Basically the node.js will act as a front end for the server infrastructure. When it gets a requests, it will place the compute request on a queue, the queue may or may not be on the same server. The entries on the queue will be taken off by a CPU farm that will do the actual calculations. The CPU farm will definitely be on other servers. The whole infrastructure would look like :-

[image]

My question is, how do I pass the results back to node.js so that it can pass it back to the client? i.e. the red arrow in the diagram.

Would I do something like this?

```
app.get(ipnRoute, function (req, res) {
    putRequestOnQueue();

    nonBlockingQueuePollForResult();

    res.end('');
});
```

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like MQTT or AMQP as a messaging engine to pass resources back and forth.  Check out the microservices techniques as well.